# Search for specific string in an Excel Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

So, I need to make an Excel Macro in VBA that will search for a string, then compare it with a pre-set string of my choice and then change the value of a cell in another Sheet.

It goes like this:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim A As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet

Dim ToCompare, Coniburo As String

Coniburo = "My String"

For Each WS In Worksheets
    For A = 1 To Rows.Count
    ToCompare = Left(Cells(A, 3), 100)
        If InStr(ToCompare, Coniburo) > 0 Then
            Sheets("Last Sheet").Cells(21, 2).Value = "233"
        End If
    Next A
Next
```

The macro works....... If I remove the first For (the one that search through sheets) and as long as I'm in a sheet where "My string" is present. Otherwise, it doesn't work. It takes a long time to process, over a minute since there are 17 sheets.

Why isn't working? I read a lot of posts here, the Microsoft Dev forum, a site called Tech on the Net, and still there is something I'm missing, but I don't know why.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is taking so long because you are looping through every row, all 1 Million +,  That is over 17 million loops.  That will take some time,  Find the last row with data on each sheet and loop to that.

Comment: You get that you are writing and rewriting `"233"` into the same cell on the last worksheet evertime, right?

Comment: You also have `Rows.Count`, which is unqualified. It's only counting the rows on the active sheet. You need to qualify that, and `Cells()` later, with `WS`, i.e. `For A = 1 to WS.Rows.Count`, and `...Left(WS.Cells(A,33),...`

Comment: @BruceWayne Adding WS in Rows and Cells fixed it! I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much, man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a With ... End With to focus the parent worksheet for each iteration of the loop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim a As Long, Coniburo As String, ws As Worksheet

    Coniburo = "My String"

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            For a = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                If CBool(InStr(Left(.Cells(a, 3), 100), Coniburo, vbTextCompare)) Then
                    Worksheets("Last Sheet").Cells(21, 2).Value = 233
                End If
            Next a
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

You need to prefix Rows, Range and Cells calls with a period like `.Rows...` or `.Range(...)` or `.Cells(...)` when inside a With ... End With block. This identifies them with the parent worksheet described by the With .. End With.

I also made the comparison case-insensitive with `vbTextCompare`.

There is the remaining problem of writing and rewriting 233 into the same cell on the same worksheet but that is another matter.

Comment: Don't worry about the 233, let me worry about the 233. And I'll try this method as well, you avoid using one extra variable, which is great for future reference. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 1):

I've bent the rules a little here but I want to show how we could use the built in FIND function to speed things up dramatically. Simply, we'll work through each sheet within column C only; we'll use the FIND function to find the ROW number where column C contains your search string.... then we'll double-check that cell to see if your search string is within the first 100 characters, per your requirement. If it is, we'll consider that a match. In addition to your result of logging "233" into the sheet "Last Page" I've included some bright green highlighting just to help see what's going on...

```
Sub findConiburo()
    Coniburo = "My String"
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws.Range("C:C")
            myName = ws.Name 'useful for debugging

            queue = 1 'will be used to queue the FIND function

            x = 0 'loop counter

            Do 'loop to find multiple results per sheet

                On Error Resume Next 'Disable error handling

                'FIND Coniburo within ws column C, log row number:
                'Note ".Cells(queue, 1)" is a relative reference to the current WS, column C
                foundRow = .Find(What:=Coniburo, After:=.Cells(queue, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
                    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                    False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

                'If no result found then an error number is stored. Perform error handling:
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    'No results found, don't do anything, exit DO to skip to next sheet:
                    Exit Do
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0 'Re-enable error handling

                If x = 0 Then
                    'first loop - log the first row result:
                    originalFoundRow = foundRow
                ElseIf foundRow = originalFoundRow Then
                    'Not the first loop. Same result as original loop = we're back at the start, so exit loop:
                    Exit Do
                End If

                'Update queue so next loop will search AFTER the previous result:
                queue = foundRow

                'check if the string is not only SOMEWHERE in the cell,
                'but specifically within the first 100 characters:
                ToCompare = Left(.Cells(foundRow, 1), 100)
                If InStr(ToCompare, Coniburo) > 0 Then
                    .Cells(foundRow, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'highlight green
                    Sheets("Last Sheet").Cells(21, 2).Value = "233"
                End If

                'Update loop counter:
                x = x + 1
            Loop
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```